# How to make the session timeout infinite in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am trying to set unlimited timeout for the session in laravel. I tried by increasing the time in `php.ini` and `.env` for session.

But I'm getting a `419 Error`.

How can I make the session persist forever in laravel?

Comment: Please explain the question clearly . What have you done in php.ini file? and where did you got that error?

Comment: I have increase the time in php.ini for the following parameter session.cookie_lifetime= 18000000 session.gc_maxlifetime = 18000000 when i login after some time 419 error is coming.

Comment: Have you tried changing it in session.php?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the

> config/session.php

change the following line

```
lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

into

```
lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 1800000),
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Then try clearing config and cache using the command :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: No still the user is getting logut in few hours

Comment: @Yash Then try to increase the time more than defined